# How to include rails ApplicationHelper module in a regular Ruby Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class in my Rails app's lib directory and I want to be able to use the helpers I created in ApplicationHelper from inside that class. I have the following:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def works
    "Yay!"
  end   

  def breaks
    session[:username]
  end
end

class MyClass
  include ApplicationHelper
end
```

The following works

```
MyClass.new.works
```

This breaks

```
MyClass.new.breaks
```

I get a message about Rails trying to delegate `session` to `controller.session`, but it can't do it because `controller` is nil.

What's the right way to include ApplicationHelper?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with including the helper, but with accessing the session.

In the normal scenario, the `ApplicationHelper` is automatically included in all controllers, and [some of the ActionView methods - including `session` - are delegated to the controller](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5abadf1613710c6e6b54e8190b66543861711b8a/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/controller_helper.rb#L10-L11) which is present in this case.

When included in a regular ruby class, there is no `controller`; so any call to these methods will throw an error saying the controller is nil.

Not sure why you would need session information in a regular ruby class.

Comment: I don't think ApplicationHelper is "automatically included in all controllers". Methods in ApplicationHelper are available in all views, but those methods will cause an error if called from the controller class.  

In my particular case, I was trying to create a config object that played nice with the helpers that were already defined (to give a little more power to the config object and limit the need to define a method in 2 places).

Comment: I decided to scrap this design and turn my config class into a config module.  Instead of trying to include the helpers into my class, I'm now including my config module into ApplicationHelper.  I'd still like to know how to access the current controller instance.  My config object was being created in the application.html.erb layout file.  Now that I think about it, I could have got the controller from the current view and initialized my config object with the controller.  That would have worked.  I'm still wondering if there's another way.